# MouseOver and MouseOut with Snippet in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I am having issues with implement something with JavaScript using Snippets in WordPress Theme. I am using Elementor to edit pages, I think is relevent to mention.

This is what I am doing; trying to implement `MouseOver` and `MouseOut` in a landing page, so the user can play videos only if they have *mouse over one section* that contains specific video while they're scrolling. I think is relevent to mention too, that the videos are background (like a header with background video) in each section, so, if is better to put them just like a "pure video" (not background) to not have problems with deep selection classes, would appreaciate the advice too.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?> 
<script>
    
    let clip = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-background-video-hosted .elementor-html5-video');
    console.log(clip);
    
    for ( let i = 0; i < clip.length; i++) {
    clip[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        console.log(clip[i]);
        clip[i].play();
    })
    clip[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        clip[i].pause();
    })
}
    
</script>

<?php } );
```

The thing is that when I try to see something in console (that's why I have some `console.log`), dont' even show me the NodeList, it's empty, also the `MouseOver` and `MouseOut` is not working, I don't know if I am selecting the wrong class (I checked lot of times) or if my code is wrong.

**[EDIT]**

An image of the html structure to understand better if I am using the right class.
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyX15.png)

I'll really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Note that: the play() and pause() methods work only with the HTML audio or videoelements. I don't know about you DOM, but please check your clip array is a audio or video array - not the div or something else.

Comment: @thốngnguyễn hello, I think I am using the right class the that element (video), but I just edited the post and just added a link to see how my html structure is at the moment.

Comment: in that case, please remove the space between two class name inside the querySelectorAll() function and try again!